# increase bandwidch with VPN+ my own connection

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to watch a video from a website (flash player).

The bandwidth of the website isn't big enough and I must often wait (my own bandwidth isn't a problem).

Is there a way to combine a connection via a VPN (I use OpenVPN) and my direct connection to the website to speed my video buffering ?

Comment: A VPN only encapsulates packets traveling over your WAN connection inside different packets. Using a VPN will actually slow throughput since it adds protocol overhead to the original packets.

Answer (score 3):

Any additional connection (including a VPN connection) will share the bandwidth that the website has.  It won't increase the overall throughput.

Comment: no because this server limit the bandwitch by user. direct connection + vpn connection= 2 users= twice the bandwidth